# node.js installed but not showing

Tags: node.js, macos, installation, terminal

I installed node.js onto my macbook air laptop and it says that the installation was successful. However, when I put in the command node -v in the terminal it's not showing up. I'm getting an error message. Does anyone know why? The error message is below:

Abort trap: 6
Home:~ user$ node -v
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: Can you try updating Xcode and Command Line Tools?

Comment: How do I do that? I know the command line but I'm not that advanced with it.